# Should I create a single file app?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have a website and I am creating an app for it using phonegap? So far I have have been updating my files and build the app every time I want to do a minor change.

My question: what is the downside to create a single html page with js (angular is) that will check the app version and download all pages needed?

Note the pages are  to be cached for long time (month- year) if the version was not updated.

Thanks

Comment: do u mean to say updating code as per changes in website?

Comment: Yes, to update the code as per changes in server?

Comment: either u do manually or use code management system like git or csv to pull the code from server

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem in doing that, in fact, is more safe in case that you have calls to APIs that you dont want to be visible to users, even some major apps do that in some cases.